# Primes in Base "c" and Factors

Tags: algorithm

I recently programmed this code after discovering a cool pattern with primes in different bases. Primes highlighted in base twelve:

[image: img]

create lines down the array of numbers. The composite numbers are coloured as grey squares and prime numbers are coloured as blue. If you'll notice, in the top row, all the primes create lines *except* the factors of 12, 2 and 3. It's easy to prove that this phenomenon occurs for any number. If

*m > 1* while *m* is a whole integer, *n = prime*, *c = composite*

*n + (m)(c) = x*

when *n* is a factor of *c*, *x* is composite because the previous equation factors out to

*(n) ( (m)(c / n) ) = x*

And as long as *n* is a factor of *c*, *c / n* is a whole number, meaning that the factored equation consists of whole numbers being multiplied together, concluding that *x* is composite for those conditions. This implies that the columns topped with a prime number that is a factor of the number furthest to the right. In the example, the columns 2 and 3 do not make lines because they are a factor of the number 12.

The reason there is an *m* in that equation and the reason it is bounded to above 1 is because the "*m*" corresponds the the *m + 1* row.

Forgive my Javascript, it was the only console language I had access to:

```js
function factor(f)    {
    var Factors = [];
    var m = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(f) + 2*Math.log(f));
    for(i=2; i <= f; i++)    {      
        if(isPrime(i) === 1)        {
            for(j=1; j <= m; j++)   {
                if(isPrime( i + j*f) === 1) {
                    break;  
                }
                if(j == m && isPrime( i + j*f) === 0)   {
                    Factors.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if(isPrime(i) === 0)    {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(Factors.indexOf(f) > -1)  {
        Factors = [f];
    }
    console.log(Factors);
}
```

What the code does is look for numbers where primes *don't* appear after a prime number in the top row.

Now, what my question is, what should the highest value of the variable *m* in the program be? Right now i only have sqrt(x) + ln(x^2) because I worked that out with some trial and error but there's gotta be a concrete value.

Comment: Your grid is in base 10. Base 12 would be 1,2,3,4,....7,8,9,a,b, 10,11,12,...18,19,1a,1b,20 etc

Comment: @EdHeal The numbers are base 10, but the grid itself is in base 12. This makes it easy to read while still illustrating the point of the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a faster algorithm or just the an upper bound for m?

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi  An upper value for m

Comment: Not the answer, but related to the patterns you observe: https://youtu.be/EK32jo7i5LQ